# How to inject an external .less file in bootstrap.less using Grunt.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, less

It's there a way to use Grunt for injecting a new line like `@import "my-custom-reset-for-bootstrap.less"` in the end of bootstrap.less. Or other ideea how can I inject my less file from outside of bootstrap package. I want to do this to keep in original state the bootstrap package.

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you create a file named, for example, `custom-bootstrap.less` and insert `@import "bootstrap";` and `@import "my-custom-reset-for-bootstrap";` there?

Comment: @AndrewDunai Thank you for your comment. That's a real useful idea, it's working perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would leave the Bootstrap file as it is and import it into your custom style file instead. The main advantage of this solution is that you can use variables, mixins and actually everything from the [original Bootstrap less file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less) in your custom style definitions.

**my-custom-reset-for-bootstrap**

```
@import "bootstrap.less";

.my-custom-class {
  color: @gray-light; //var from Bootstrap variable.less file
}
```

In this case you won't need to do anything after upgrading Bootstrap files to newer version.